# capture child record change in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I need to capture record page save to be capture in my LWC component but it's not triggering my component

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getCommentsApex from '@salesforce/apex/ElementControllor.getComments';

export default class CommentChatConversation extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track comments =[];
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId'})
    captureLDS({ data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.callApex();
        }
    }
    callApex() {
        getCommentsApex({ workItemId: this.recordId })
            .then(result => {
                this.comments = result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('--' + error);
            });
    }
}
```

Did I miss anything?

I need to call my apex method when ever record page gets updated or from external users.

Comment: What are the actual sObject changes you are seeking to react to? Are you trying to monitor child records changes? Please [edit] to add details.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to capture child records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getRecord()` wire adapter does not provision you new data when a child of the record you're retrieving changes. Your current approach will not work.

You have a handful of options to explore, all of which will require writing more code:

- Write a trigger on the child object that causes a DML operation on the parent, as a way to force `getRecord()` to be invoked and thereby triggering your Apex refresh.
- Use an event-driven API, such as Platform Events (fired by an Apex trigger on the child object) or Change Data Capture, to observe changes to the child object and refresh accordingly.
- Poll on a schedule for new child objects.

Comment: I am building this for AppExchange, if I have implemented PE can my app installed in the professional edition?

Comment: No, Platform Events [are not supported in Professional Edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_considerations.htm).

Comment: You will get better answers if you edit your post to state (1) that you are observing child record changes; (2) what the actual sObject types are; (3) that you are building a managed package; and (4) you have to support Professional Edition. Without that context, it's hard to give you a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, @David for your support, just a quick clarification, if I add PE in trigger flow and include it in my app package can professional edition org can still install this app without it?

Comment: The linked documentation is very explicit: "Platform events aren’t supported in Professional and Group Edition orgs. Installation of a package that contains platform event objects fails in those orgs."

Comment: Many thanks, I will keep a manual button and ask the user to pull changes, Is there any way based on edition install metadata?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to Change Data capture with something like this:

```
subscribe('/data/' + changeEventObject, -1, handleObjectUpdate).then(response => {
     console.log('Successfully subscribed to : ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
});
```

where `handleObjectUpdate` is a callback function that you'll do whatever you need to do when a change to the object is detected.

Comment: Do you mean platform event? I am afraid that PE will not be in Manage Package.

Comment: No, change data capture is a feature in Salesforce. You can Google info on it. You set an object up for CDC in an org, then you can subscribe to changes on that object in your components. A trigger or someone else in the org can make a change and you can pick the up on the component for whoever is viewing it.

Comment: But CDC can't support professional edition.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm

Comment: Also, CDC can't give change record ID in response.